# How can I force an update in the WPF UI?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm using MVVM, so I have a class that represents my data.  It implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and I have public properties with their set and get accessor methods.
The set on each property raises the NotifyPropertyChanged event.

I have a status field in my XAML which is a rectangle.  The background colour is bound to a property in my ViewModel, which is a property of enum type.  I have a Converter that converts the enum values to colours.
This works just fine some of the time.  At startup, it sets the status to Disconnected, and the rectangle goes grey.
However, just before I call my code to make the connection, I set the status to Connecting, and the rectangle is supposed to turn orange, but it remains grey.
When the connection is made, the status changes to Connected, and the rectangle turns green.

When debugging, it hits the breakpoints in the property set method and also hits the code where the colour orange is selected in the Converter, yet it doesn't update the display to show orange.

It may be that the code to make the connection is hogging the CPU and the UI doesn't get the chance to update until the connection is made, when it turns green as expected.  Unfortunately, the code that makes the connection is not mine, so I can't change it.

So my question is: Is it possible to make the UI force the update before I call the connection code?
I tried adding a delay, but that didn't work.
As it's happening in my VM code (rather than code-behind), I don't see how to link back to objects in the XAML to update them.

Comment: The code that makes the connection is certainly not "*hogging the CPU*" but probably just blocking the UI thread. The usual workaround is to make it async and await it, or wrap it in a Task that would be awaited.

Comment: Yeah.  Blocking the UI thread was what I meant.  The term escaped me at the time.

Answer (score 2):

> It may be that the code to make the connection is hogging the CPU and the UI doesn't get the chance to update until the connection is made, when it turns green as expected. Unfortunately, the code that makes the connection is not mine, so I can't change it.

Freezing the GUI while doing something is not acceptable in 2020. Keep that in 1980, please.

And it doesn't matter if you force enough message cycles to update the GUI before freezing it, you're still freezing it. Any mouse or keyboard click during that will ghost your window and pop up a close dialog in Windows 10 -- understandably so, your code behaves exactly like broken, freezing code.

Either get over your fear of changing existing code, and refactor it with proper `async` code, or just throw it in a separate thread.

Comment: That fixed it.  I put the connection code in a separate thread and the UI updates perfectly now.  Thanks.